# xsl:attributes strips the "content"

Tags: plone, diazo

I'm writing some rules in Diazo. I want, in case the user browses the "viewer" section (a browser view, not a real plone folder), to drop the "selected" class for the "home" tab in the globalnav and put "selected" class for the "viewer" tab.

```
<replace css:content="#portal-globalnav" css:theme="#portal-globalnav" />
<drop if-path="viewer/" 
        css:content="#portaltab-index_html"
        attributes="class" />    
<xsl:template if-path="viewer/"
          match="//li[@id='portaltab-viewer']/">
<xsl:attribute name="class">selected</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

But the result it's a right li portaltab-viewer with the "selected" class, but without any content inside! I obtain an empty "li" tag in the portal-globalnav O.O

What's wrong?
Vito

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to recurse into the content of the element with xsl:apply-templates. Try:

```
<replace if-path="/viewer" css:content-children="li#portaltab-viewer"><xsl:attribute name="class">selected</xsl:attribute><xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/></replace>
```

The lack of whitespace before the xsl:attribute is necessary as I don't think I ever got around to making Diazo ignore whitespace around xsl:* elements.

Comment: I also tried this rule with the href attribute, but in this case your code doesn't work. :-/

Comment: In that case you should reduce it down to the minimum failing example that can be run with diazorun so that I can reproduce the problem.